# Does it actually matter if you import packages in first component mount?

Tags: reactjs, import, gatsby

I'm curious if the two code snippets below actually matter in terms of performance. On the first one, we have our good old way to import packages. Just import 'em directly at the top level of the code. On the second one, I'm setting the state once the import statement finishes inside `React.useEffect()`

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

export default function SomeFunc() {
    ....
}
```

```
import React from "react";

export default function SomeFunc() {
     const [link, setLink] = useState();


     React.useEffect(() => {
       import("gatsby").then(({ Link }) => setLink(Link));
     }, []);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the described case, it will. Since you are blocking the `<Link>` component usage until the package is loaded, even more, if you are waiting for the DOM tree (because of the `useEffect` with empty deps(`[]`)). With the native approach (the first one), you are bundling the package at the build-time so it will have better performance overall since it's a dependency used by Gatsby itself.

There's a big however, the dynamic imports add the huge benefit of reducing the bundle size, the payload response, especially in SPA applications, but their usage must be coherent to the package lazy-loaded.

I would recommend https://blog.mgechev.com/2019/05/11/dynamic-imports-javascript/.